# Not able to get console logs after installing Sentry(Raven)

Tags: angular, debugging, error-handling, sentry, raven

I have configured raven to get the error logs, I'm getting the logs successfully in sentry dashboard,but after it's set up the console logs are gone.

I even tried by setting the autoBreadcrumbs to be false while configuring, still no luck

```
Raven
  .config('mysentrydsn', {
    autoBreadcrumbs: {
        'console': true,
    }
  })
  .install();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside your providers in `app.module.ts`

```
environment.production ? {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: RavenErrorHandler} : []
```

And create a new RavenErrorHandler

```
export class RavenErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(err: any): void {
    Raven.captureException(err);
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```